# EE, SSL, and insecure content

Tags: security, secure

I've installed an SSL on my server and I'm forcing https:// via htaccess. The entire site needs to be secured. Unfortunately, the browsers are complaining of insecure content.

For example:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{stylesheet='assets/css.layout'}">
{site_url}
```

These evaluate to a URL that begin with `http://`.

I'm still exploring the problem, so there might be other issues.

What do I need to do in EE so that I don't get URLs that begin with `http://`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your EE config.php / site configuration, is your site URL set with http:// or https:// ? If it's not the latter, try that to see if it solves the issue. I think EE matches the site_url to the exact URL (and protocol) that you set in this configuration variable.

The trickier thing is when you have a site that's partially under HTTP and partially HTTPS. In that case, you definitely need to use add-ons and/or link site URLs coded another way to properly traverse from one to the other. (I set global variables in the config for `{global:site_url}` and `{global:site_ssl_url}`, and use those in my templates.)

Finally, for your CSS URL, you can also reference it like:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css.layout">
```

or

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//yoursite.com/assets/css.layout">
```

(Note that web browsers will resolve the // in the URL to either http or https, to match the protocol of the current page.)

Finally, if you have the option, move your CSS to a static file outside of EE--this will improve your site performance noticeably.

Answer (score 5):

> It's because EE variables don't detect or utilise https by default, so
>   you have to set them in code. The easiest way is to use an add-on:
>
> http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/https-support
>
> http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/dm-force-ssl
>
> http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/force-ssl (commercial)
>
> (In no particular order) I've not used any of these so can't recommend
>   a specific one as I use my own plugin.
>
> *via: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12211420/25286*

Also, here is an older article, but with some useful tips:
https://exp-resso.com/blog/post/2011/08/securing-your-expressionengine-website-with-https